# 36 year old clothes dryer has a 9 amp differential between legs what may the problem be?

Tags: electrical

The clothes dryer has 12.5 amps on one leg and 21.5 amps on the second leg. Could this become a major problem with unbalanced loads on the main panel increasing the amperage on the neutral?  The dryer is 36 years old and is still drying the clothes but I am concerned about putting my main panel in an unbalanced load.
Is it time for a new dryer even though it is still drying the clothes?

Comment: Unless it tosses the drum though a wall I would keep it working.  You will save a few bucks a year on electricity with a new one, but the new ones do not seem to last as long.

Comment: Thank you for your input my dryer is 240 v and I had several rome's wires leaning against the #4 ground which melted the rome's on the neutral not the hot or it would have tripped the breaker. I am suspecting an unbalanced leg to increase the amperage on the  neutral leg to melt the rome's and possibly caused bu the unbalanced 9 amp leg plus to try to go to ground ????

Comment: I will certainly splice the damaged wires in a j-box but need to find why this happened and my first thought was the dryer and am now checking all the loads once again. I have never experienced anything like this before.

Comment: Not saying there is not a problem with yours, but unless the repairs are close or above 50% of a new one, it is worth keeping.

Comment: The Melting of the Romex scares me to it got that hot to melt it.

Comment: I have three grounds in close proximity to a 200 amp panel two 8' rods outside 6' apart and the one where the romex melted was a #4 solid on the cold water pipe I have continuity to earth outside my house all copper with a jumper at the meter.

Comment: It's called a motor. That only runs on one leg...

Comment: You'd have to provide a lot more details, probably in a new question, to get into the melting Romex. First guess on that since you provide no detail about it (but do for the ground it melted to) is that it's undersized for the load *e.g.* 14 or 12Ga on a 30A dryer circuit. Or that it's a /2 Romex possibly undersized with neutral on the grounding wire for a NEMA 10 dryer outlet. Because all that's legitimately on Neutral here is 9A, and that won't even melt 14Ga. And "several" Romex cables would involve ones not connected to the dryer, unless something else hacked was done. So; Full details.

Comment: You put a larger unbalanced load on every time you make toast, or coffee, or run a hairdryer or space heater or waffle iron. Or any other strictly 120V appliance. It's not a problem. The fact that you think it is might indicate some need for further learning. Overloaded neutrals happen in /3 cables where someone who doesn't understand MWBCs screws one up, mostly.

Comment: How are you measuring the amps??  It is a little weird to do current measurements on both legs of a 240V circuit.

Comment: I would assume it's being measured using a clamp meter.

Answer (score 5):

### Dryers are 120V devices.  Mostly.

They put the largest *number* of their loads between one 120V hot wire and neutral.  Timer, light, tumble motor, blower.  All 120V.

Oh, dryers have one more load I almost forgot.  They have a heater of some kind.  That's either natural gas (so a couple watts for a gas valve)... or it's a HUGE ELECTRIC HEATING ELEMENT that goes across both legs, because it needs 240V.   So in the latter case, yeah, dryers are 240V, *but they're still also 120V*.

So wait. If electric dryers have 240V loads, why don't they just make the whole kit-n-kaboodle 240V - tumble motor, blower, light etc.?  [Then you'd have zero parts commonality with gas dryers](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4?t=747) which easily fit on a 120V circuit... and that would only make things more expensive.

Thus it is 100% normal for dryers to draw more on one leg than the other.  Yours seems higher than I might expect, so it might indicate a fault, but I don't know what the unit's meant to do, so I would call it "inconclusive".

### The power company can handle minor imbalance

Because with a bunch of loads in a house, it averages out somewhat... and a bunch of houses on a transformer, it averages out a lot more.  And even if all the homeowners conspired to put their loads on the same leg, it would still not matter to the power company, because their 120/240V transformer would balance it because of how transformers work.  The only problem is if you load only one leg on a transformer, you cut its capacity in half.  But that's their problem.